Convert from long to wide format in tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(continent = c("europe", "africa"),
                 region = c("north", "west", "south"),
                 number = 1:18)

I am trying to convert from a long to a wide format but the following syntaxis didn't work.
df_long <- df |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = region,
              values_from = number)

The following message appears in my RStudio:
Warning message:
Values from `number` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
• Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
• Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} %>%
  dplyr::group_by(continent, region) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  dplyr::filter(n > 1L) 
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
> head(df_long)
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  continent north     west      south    
  <chr>     <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 europe    <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>
2 africa    <int [3]> <int [3]> <int [3]>


Although I didn't get any error message, but I got the same result as you did. What kind of result were you expecting to get?

In this example, I need the values in the "number" column for each region by continent.

Since the groups are not unique adding a unique identifier will help, something like df %>% mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = c(continent, region)) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from=region, values_from=number)

@AndreWildberg, I applied your coding to my dataset, and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much! :)
